# Finding month preg-match

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I'm checking a webpage stored in a PHP variable via CURL. Within the webpage will be a month name and year and also a name so the webpage will look something like:

```
December 2012
Name: Jack Brown
```

I want a pregmatch to find data so i can display it like:

```
For Jack Brown - December 2012
```

I have tried

```
\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|...|Dec(?:ember)?) (?:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3})(?=\D|$)
```

but it comes up with an error

Comment: you should show what you've tried. also, is the "variable" returning all that in one string? if so, it won't be a simple matter. if it's different variables, you can just create your own using those variable.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you remembering to use delimiters? Showing the PHP code where you use this regex could also be helpful.

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: Yep, sounds like you are forgetting [delimiters](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a snippet for you, so you can start from here

```
$str = 'December 2012 Name: Jack Brown';
$ptr = "/^(?P<month>:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Dec(?:ember)?) (?P<year>:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3}) (Name:(?P<name>(.*)))/";
preg_match($ptr, $str, $data);
echo 'For '.trim($data['name']).' - '.$data['month'].' '.$data['year'];
```

the result will be

```
'For Jack Brown - December 2012'
```

this is a array

```
Array
(
    [0] => December 2012 Name: Jack Brown
    [month] => December
    [1] => December
    [year] => 2012
    [2] => 2012
    [3] => Name: Jack Brown
    [name] =>  Jack Brown
    [4] =>  Jack Brown
    [5] =>  Jack Brown
)
```

also i try with

```
'February 2005 Name: Bob' => 'For Bob - February 2005'
```

ps. you can add more month i just lazy to add, cheers