# PHP finding month and year from a string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is what I have tried so far getting year from any type of string.

```
<?php

  $variable = [
      'Well year is 1967 month jan',
      'year is 1876 but month January',
      'HOLLA April Evening 2017',
      'DOLLA-May 2020',
      'OH-YESApril 2019 (IGNORE)',
      'Just a sample String without year ok lets just add 1'
  ];
  foreach ($variable as $value) {
      if(ContainsNumbers($value)){
           $input = preg_replace('/^[^\d]*(\d{4}).*$/', '\1', $value);
            $input = (int)$input;
                if($input>1000 && $input<2100)
                {
                   var_dump($input);
                }                   
      } 
  }
  function ContainsNumbers($String){
    return preg_match('/\\d/', $String) > 0;
}
?>
```

Here is an **output** of above code

```
int(1967)
int(1876)
int(2017)
int(2020)
int(2019)
```

The only thing I want now is getting month from the string . 
For month I am getting help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852808/finding-month-preg-match) but no luck so far :- 
I don't know what to add in `$data`

```
$str = 'December 2012 Name: Jack Brown';
$ptr = "/^(?P<month>:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Dec(?:ember)?) (?P<year>:19[7-9]\d|2\d{3}) (Name:(?P<name>(.*)))/";
 var_dumb(preg_match($ptr, $str, $data););
```

[Here is a play ground](https://paiza.io/projects/yYM1KX7fFmvi2Tbw2OCqBw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, almost everyone calls the third parameter to `preg_match` `$matches`, so I'm going to go with the nomenclature here.

If the RegEx matches, the third parameter will be an array with numeric indexes for each items, as well named-indexes if you have any named matches. So you are looking for:

```php
if(preg_match($ptr, $str, $matches)){
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Which will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => December 2012 Name: Jack Brown
    [month] => December
    [1] => December
    [year] => 2012
    [2] => 2012
    [3] => Name: Jack Brown
    [name] =>  Jack Brown
    [4] =>  Jack Brown
    [5] =>  Jack Brown
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Chris haas has explained it very clearly but any one would like to use array approach then kindly use this :-

```
<?php
$variable = [
      'Well year is 1967 month jan',
      'year is 1876 but month January',
      'HOLLA April Evening 2017',
      'DOLLA-May 2020',
      'OH-YESApril 2019 (IGNORE)',
      'Just a sample String without year ok lets just add 1'
  ];
  $months = array(
    'January' => 'jan',
    'February' => 'feb',
    'March' => 'mar',
    'April' => 'apr',
    'May' => 'may',
    'June' => 'jun',
    'July ' => 'jul',
    'August' => 'aug',
    'September' => 'sep',
    'October' => 'oct',
    'November' => 'nov',
    'December' => 'dec',
);
  foreach ($variable as $string) {
      foreach($months as $key => $value){
            if (strpos($string, $value) !== false) {
               var_dump($value) ;
            }
              if (strpos($string, $key) !== false) {
                 var_dump($value) ;
            }
  }

}
die();

?>
```

**Output**

```
string(3) "jan"
string(3) "jan"
string(3) "apr"
string(3) "may"
string(3) "apr"
```